# Junit create report without ant/maven

Tags: java, junit, report

Is it possible to create a report from JUnit without Ant or Maven? Because I call the tests with velocitycode, and the velocitycodes calls a method. And that method calls all the tests. So I can get a response from it, the failures/errors/runs etc. But I want to create a report with it.. Or do I need to create html stuff by myself?

I created the methods and testmethods in Java, so I will do everything in Java, except the call, thats in Velocity code.

Velocitycode:

> ${custom.test}

Java code:

> public void getTest(){ 
>       junit.textui.TestRunner runner = new junit.textui.TestRunner(); 
>       TestResult testresult = Junit.textui.TestRunner.run(runner.getTest(MyTestClass.class.getName()));
>       
> }

Comment: When you say 'calls velocitycode' can you be a bit more specific? Do you mean that there is a test runner which comes from velocity? Can you be a bit more explicit, and post some example code please?

Comment: I added the code. With the velocitycode I call the method getTest in Java. And the method getTest runs the tests

Answer (score 1):

You will need the ant library. But with this code you can create an XML report and use it in other pograms. Such as Jenkins.

```
public static void getTest(){
    String pathToReports = "C:\\path\\to\\the\\Reports";
    Project project = new Project();

    try {
        new File(pathToReports).mkdir();
        JUnitTask task = new JUnitTask();

        project.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir",pathToReports);
        task.setProject(project);

        FormatterElement.TypeAttribute type = new FormatterElement.TypeAttribute();
        type.setValue("xml");

        FormatterElement formater = new FormatterElement();   
        formater.setType(type);
        task.addFormatter(formater);

        JUnitTest test = new JUnitTest(YOURTEST.class.getName());
        test.setTodir(new File(pathToReports));

        task.addTest(test);         
        task.execute(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so.  But you might be able to use ant as a library instead of a tool, and use the same code that the tool uses to generate these reports.

Comment: I don't understand? I run the JUnit test inside the code, but then? How can I use the 'Ant Library' to create the report inside the code?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're looking for a library that can somehow take the output from JUnit and format it (is that right?)  My thinking was that since Ant can do this, and Ant is available as a jar, you can leverage the same classes that Ant does to achieve what you're looking for.  Take a look at this class, for instance: http://www.jajakarta.org/ant/ant-1.6.1/docs/en/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/junit/SummaryJUnitResultFormatter.html.  You'd have to check ant's source to see how the class is used.

Comment: Yes you are right, but I can't find in the Library how to create the reports. Do you have any examples or tutorials or something like that?