# How to generate xslt reports without using ANT

Tags: java, xslt, ant, selenium, testng

I am working on selenium testing project. I need to build XSLT reports with out using ANT.
I refereed this link: [Junit create report without ant/maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890530/junit-create-report-without-ant-maven) ,
but the given solution is for JUnit. I am using TestNG.
So is it possible to create xslt reports with TestNG without using ANT.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score -1):

Use the following process:

- Install [testng-xslt](https://github.com/prashanth-sams/testng-xslt-1.1.2)
- Configure the report [using testng-xslt](http://seleniumtesting-nx.blogspot.com/2012/03/testng-xslt-report-generation.html)